# What is "Metatron's cube" in Judaism ? Is it truly mentionned in Jewish mysticism?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, malach-angel, symbols-symbology

according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metatron's_Cube) The derivation of Metatron's Cube from the Flower of Life, which Jewish texts states, was excluded from human experience during the exile from Eden.

Is Metatron's cube mentioned in Kabbalah ? If yes, what it means ?

Comment: Note: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Articles_for_deletion/Metatron's_Cube

Comment: These are energon cubes, which are "the safest form of energon, used for transportation and storage". See here:
http://img02.deviantart.net/d8de/i/2011/170/6/8/megatron_with_an_energon_cube_by_8att9477-d3jas4y.jpg

Answer (score -3):

Metatrons cube is a merkava cube it represents crown on tree of life which is described as absolute compassion as well as the 13 principles of mercy which are made up of 18 Hebrew words (wikipedia 13 principles of mercy)

Metatrons cube is 18 -the thirteen spheres of the fruit of life and 78 lines are drawn center to center of the 13 spheres forming 5 platonic solids(3d).

(78 in math being a harshad (joy giving) number as well as a  sphenic number and the amount of gifts in 12 days of Christmas song and the number of a typical tarot deck).

Metatrons cube is a kind of mandala. In the center are seven circles. The seven circles are the seed of life which is interconnected to the tree of life.( 32 paths 22 Hebrew letters and ten spheres PS. Only 32 crystal point groups are know in science)

In metatrons cube the central spheres are surrounded by a star of David two triangles 180 degrees each make for 360 degrees thus turning seed to tree of life's crown (keter). By using centrifugal clockwise spinning to do so.
The cube is activated by intention combined with a lifestyle that involves conscious breathing as a regular and preferably constant practice. It would also involve spiritual study and prayer.
Support of a spiritual teacher and community necessary for such a journey..I activated merkava cubethe a bit less then two years ago after five years of constant mindfulness breathing practice and I have noticed a marked improvement in my daily life as well as overall feeling of well-being . Gradually it happens.

Comment: Sources, please?